How to detect when the windows menu is open and when it is closed in python?
I have had a look at the winapi module and stuff but I don't know how I would detect it. Currently I am using key presses to detect when the menu is opened and closed but this is unreliable because when you click on an app to start it the windows menu closes. I would appreciate if someone can tell me how to detect it a different way.closed open
I tried using a key press library to detect it but it was unreliable as it couldn't detect half the stuff I wanted it to do. I was expecting it to be able to properly detect when the windows menu is open and when it is closed.

from typing import Optional
from ctypes import wintypes, windll, create_unicode_buffer

def getForegroundWindowTitle() -> Optional[str]:
  hWnd = windll.user32.GetForegroundWindow()
  length = windll.user32.GetWindowTextLengthW(hWnd)
  buf = create_unicode_buffer(length + 1)
  windll.user32.GetWindowTextW(hWnd, buf, length + 1)

# 1-liner alternative: return buf.value if buf.value else None
if buf.value:
    return buf.value
else:
    return None
if getForegroundWindowTitle() == "Search":
   #gets the window in focus, fortunately windows focuses the start menu whenever the key is pressed, the window name is called search
   #do something here
   pass


This is the answer but unfortunately I can only accept in two days from now. Bye!
